# Copy multiple files in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I want to copy multiple files using bat file. I have succeeded with this script.

```
xcopy /-y "C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\bat\test1.csv" "C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\"

xcopy /-y "C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\bat\test2.csv" "C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\"
```

and I tried to do it in one line, so I use this script

```
for %I in (C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\bat\test1.csv C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\bat\test2.csv) do copy %I C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\
```

however it is not working. Can anyone correct my code?

Comment: An important part of posting a question on Stack Overflow is to specify in what way it is "not working." If there is an error message, copy and paste it as text into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `%` with another `%`.

A single `%` is used to represent command line parameters.

```
for %%I in (C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\bat\test1.csv C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\bat\test2.csv) do copy %%I C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\
```

If you're curious to see what is happening, temporarily add `pause` to your batch file to see what it's doing before the window closes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question says multiple files, but you show only two.

Here are a few examples for you.

You may just get away with:

```bat
Copy /-Y "%UserProfile%\Desktop\bat\test*.csv" "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
```

If you wanted to use a wildcard in a loop.

From a batch file:

```bat
@For %%A In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\bat\test*.csv") Do @Copy /-Y "%%A" "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
```

Or from the Command prompt:

```bat
For %A In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\bat\test*.csv") Do @Copy /-Y "%A" "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
```

In a loop with wildcards limiting it to specified names only.

From a batch file:

```bat
@For %%A In (1 2) Do @Copy /-Y "%UserProfile%\Desktop\bat\test%%A.csv" "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
```

Or from the Command prompt:

```bat
For %A In (1 2) Do @Copy /-Y "%UserProfile%\Desktop\bat\test%A.csv" "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
```

In all cases, you could still use `XCopy` but it isn't required since you're using none of its features. *Additionally it was superseded by `RoboCopy` as far back as Windows Vista!*

For information on the use of a command, enter its name at the Command prompt with the question mark option e.g. `Copy /?`