# Windows copy command copies only 1 file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy

In a folder, I have 4 files, for example:

```
install.bat
program.exe
service.exe
uninstall.bat
```

I am interested to know why the following command copies all `bat` files to `C:\Temp`

```
copy *.bat C:\Temp
```

But this command only copies the first file, ignoring the rest?

```
copy *.bat+*.exe C:\Temp
```

It sees *all* the files because the output lists them, but only one is copied.

```
install.bat
program.exe
service.exe
uninstall.bat
    1 file(s) copied.
```

Of course I can use two commands, one for each extensions, but why does it copy only one file, and how to specify multiple sources at once?

#### EDIT

The documentation of the command (i.e. `copy /?`) is the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\yanickrochon>copy /?
Copies one or more files to another location.

COPY [/D] [/V] [/N] [/Y | /-Y] [/Z] [/L] [/A | /B ] source [/A | /B]
     [+ source [/A | /B] [+ ...]] [destination [/A | /B]]

  source       Specifies the file or files to be copied.
  /A           Indicates an ASCII text file.
  /B           Indicates a binary file.
  /D           Allow the destination file to be created decrypted
  destination  Specifies the directory and/or filename for the new file(s).
  /V           Verifies that new files are written correctly.
  /N           Uses short filename, if available, when copying a file with a
               non-8dot3 name.
  /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /-Y          Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /Z           Copies networked files in restartable mode.
  /L           If the source is a symbolic link, copy the link to the target
               instead of the actual file the source link points to.

The switch /Y may be preset in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.  Default is
to prompt on overwrites unless COPY command is being executed from
within a batch script.

To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files
for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).
```

This question is about the follow part:

```
COPY source + source destination
```

If the command accepts multiple sources, how does it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy multiple files in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837622/copy-multiple-files-in-bat-file)

Comment: Well, the `+` operator of `copy` is intended to concatenates files, not to specify multiple file masks to copy; you could however simply use multiple commands: `copy *.bat C:\Temp` and `copy *.exe C:\Temp`…

Comment: @aschipfl AH! That makes more sense, file concatenation. Got it. Because, this is definitely NOT clear in the help context.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The most unclear thing is that even when you specify a *directory* as the destination (which is *not* a single file as mentioned in the usage text), `copy` concatenates, or appends, all source files to a single destination file whose name is the very first match of the first source mask as soon as one `+` is encountered. This is a somewhat terrible design in my opinion…

Comment: I disagree with your last comment, to be honest, @YanickRochon. The very bottom of the help output you posted specifies _"To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files
for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format)."_. Though the word concatenation is not used, it does state `append` `:)`

Comment: What typically happens is that you specify the destination file to append to (concatenate) however, if you use the destination as a folder, it will simply use the first file name found and append the remainder of the matches to it.

Comment: Then on your question of how to specify multple sources, well simply use  a for loop from `cmd` as `for %i in (*.exe *.bat) do copy "%~i" "C:\Temp"` and from `batch-file` as `for %%i in (*.exe *.bat) do copy "%%~i" "C:\Temp"` ofcourse you can add as many extensions as you like in there.

Comment: @Gerhard, what seems to be unclear in the help is the difference between `copy *.bat dir` and `copy *.bat + *.exe dir`; the first example copies all files into the destination directory `dir`, while the second example creates a *single* `.bat` file in the destination directory; in both situations, the specified destination is *not* a single file…

Comment: Note: if you specify a single file (or folder) as destination, all source files are copied into one file. To get separate files, you need  a wildcard for the destination too: `copy "*.bat" "NewFolder\*"`. Better use the newer and much better `xcopy` command (`copy` is mainly kept for compatibility) or even `robocopy` (which is more new and shiny, but sometimes a bit of an overload for simple tasks)

Comment: I guess if English is not your native language the word `append` may not mean the same thing to everyone.

Comment: @aschipfl, true, I suppose that part is unclear. However there is some documentation somewhere which specifies that it will assume the first name as the destination name, if no destination file is specified.. Windows is not the same as linux though, so we do not have the `man` function here which is more detailed than `help` or `/`?

Comment: @Gerhard Do you know the Microsoft documentation (manual) page for the Windows command [copy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy)? The __Remarks__ section contains two points relevant here. The first one starts with "If you don't specify a destination file, a copy is created with the same name ..." and the second one below starts with "If you specify more than one file in source, the copy command combines them all into a single file using the file name specified in destination." So copy behavior is quite clear in my opinion for this use case.

Comment: @Mofi, that is the documentation I was refering to in my last comment yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@for %e in (bat exe) do (@XCOPY "C:\source\*.%e" C:\tmp /C /S /I /F /H)
```

Just put this to cmd and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware of `XCOPY`. My question is regarding the `COPY` command-line arguments specifically. The outcome is not an issue, but the API usage is.

Comment: ... and the same solution can be applied to `COPY` command, isn't it? And such a solution was [posted already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71160108/windows-copy-command-copies-only-1-file#comment125788953_71160108) in the comments above...